# how to use nodemon to inherit from another script

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have a script that runs a nodejs app

package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js --inspect --other-flags ....",
    "start:inspect": "npm run start -- --inspect",
    "start:watch": "nodemon app.js ..."
  }
    }
```

as you can see in the script "start:inspect" in inherit all flags from "start" and adds "--inspect"

I want to inherit all "start" flags into "start:watch" but with `nodemon` without manual copying

something like `"start:watch": "npm run start -- nodemon"`

Comment: Why not do `"start:watch": "nodemon npm start"` or `"start:watch": "nodemon yarn start"`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an environment variable for the command, like `"start:watch": "export CMD=nodemon; npm run start"` and `"start": "$CMD app.js ..."`